# How to define method of class outside of class?

Tags: python, class, methods

In C++ we can easily define methods outside of class:

```cpp
struct X {
   int a, b ;

   // member function declaration only
   int add();
};

// define member function outside its class declaration
int X::add() { return a + b; }
```

I want to do the same thing (or something like this in python) but I don't know how

I saw some solutions to similar problems but they included creating some new functions like this:

```py
def my_func(self_class, arg):
    # do something with arg
    return something

class MyClass:
    function = my_func
```

Is it possible to define method outside of class without creating unnecessary functions?

Comment: What is "unnecessary" about the second example? It does exactly what your C++ code segment does, and you have to define the function *somewhere* for it to exist...

Comment: This is just how Python works. You could add the method in one line as a `lambda` but that limits what it can do.

Comment: @KrishnanShankar If I create new function this function can be used without class and it doesn't look ok

Comment: @AsKreY The point is that this is a very unconventional thing to do in Python. As an interpreted language, Python doesn't support the fancy definitions of C++ as mentioned, and the only way to define a method outside a class is as you have shown in the second code block (creating a function and assigning it as an attribute to the class). The best solution is most likely to rethink why exactly you want a method defined outside the class, and preferably to refactor it so methods are defined "in" the class.

Comment: You could `del my_func` after assigning it to the class, then it's not available to be used anywhere outside the class. (As per the example "The def way" in @RaymondHettinger's answer.)

Comment: @AsKreY In fact, functions defined in a class can also use them directly by class names, without requiring that the first parameter must be a class instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The lambda way

You example can be done with `lambda` and `=`:

```
class X:
    pass

X.add = lambda s: s.a + s.b
```

### The def way

The `def` keyword won't allow you to assign directly to a class, but you can make a function, assign it, and then delete it.   While this isn't what you were hoping for, it is likely the best you can do:

```
class X:
    pass

def add(s):
    return s.a + s.b

X.add = add
del add
```

Comment: Are there any edge case issues with `X.add = classmethod(lambda cls: ...)` to add a class method, or does that work fine too?

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't allow you to define functions in a namespace for another. You can only assign functions to class after defining them. If you want to avoid manual assignment, you can define a simple decorator to help you:

```
def methodof(tp):
    def setter(func):
        setattr(tp, func.__name__, func)
        return func
    return setter
```

Test:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
...
>>> @methodof(Foo)
... def hello(self):
...     print('hello')
...
>>> Foo().hello()
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess I am not sure what you're trying to avoid unless you have functions you want to use in many classes.  In that case I would make a base class and inherit it.

As for your second example, calling an external function means you need to explicitly pass "self" since the instance won't do that for you. Another reason I prefer inheritance.

The example is very basic so I am not sure what you wish to achieve.  For example add can be built into the class using an overload of `__add__`.  I do that with classes for Vectors.

Comment: The binding to an instance (so `self` is available without being explicitly passed) can be achieved, as in @MechanicPig and @RaymondHettinger's answers.  Agreed though, there are often better ways to do this in Python!